# Applying shadow color using feColorMatrix tag looks dull in all the browsers, Why?

Tags: filter, shadow, svg-filters, dropshadow, colormatrixfilter

I created a drop shadow in SVG using feColorMatrix for the shadow, so its kind of blue(rgba(62, 77, 184, 0)).

```
    <feColorMatrix result="output_0" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.3 0 0 0 0 0.7 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
```

The outcome should be the same blue color rgba(62, 77, 184, 1).

The SVG filter seems to render the color a bit too light. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Your math is a bit off & you need to specify sRGB. The color matrix should be:

```
<feColorMatrix result="output_0" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" type="matrix"values="0 0 0 0 0.243 0 0 0 0 0.302 0 0 0 0 0.7215 0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use [color-interpolation:"sRGB"](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3131) as property or CSS style for the filter/feColorMatrix tag. [What is color interpolation?](https://howaboutanorange.com/blog/2011/08/10/color_interpolation/) [How it works?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKnqECcg6Gw)
>
> `I spend more time to find the reason behind this issue because When I googled it, I didn't see any clear explanation and felt nobody faced kind of issue. After the so much of hard work, I figured it out the solution so I came here to raise the question and share the answer here. Hope Someone will get help from this.`